# CLOB : JdbcTemplate : c3p0 - how reuse the same connection?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, c3p0, clob

I've inherited a project which has the following setup:

- spring framework : 3.2.2
- oracle drivers : ojdbc6.jar : 11.2.0.4
- c3p0 for connection pooling : 0.9.1.2
- it utilizes dynamic datasource routing, inspired I reckon by this article http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

The declared class and one of the methods that is used to do the queries looks like the following

```
public class DataSourceServiceImpl extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport implements DataSourceService {
...
    public List<Map<String, Object>> valueList(String dataSource, Object[] params, String sql) throws DataAccessException {
        DataSourceContextHolder.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return getSimpleJdbcTemplate().getJdbcOperations().queryForList(sql, params);
    }
}
```

The sample SQL:

> SELECT samplefield FROM sampletable WHERE SDE.ST_INTERSECTS(SHAPE, SDE.ST_GEOMETRY(?, ?)) = 1 AND SHAPE IS NOT NULL

The problem is, that if the input string (representing geometry) exceeds the Oracle driver's 4000 character limit, we get the

> ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

In other words, this means that queryForList (and whatever is behind it) doesnt automatically handle the strings that exceed the limit.

After some research, I've realized that I have to use the c3p0 OracleUtils to generate a temporary Clob. So I've modified the code to check for the parameters and modify them accordingly:

```
try {           
        Connection conn =  getConnection(); 

        for (Object obj: params){           
            if (obj instanceof String && obj.toString().length() > 4000){           
                Clob clob = OracleUtils.createTemporaryCLOB(conn, true, 10);                    
                clob.setString(1, (String)obj);
                clobs.add(clob);
                params[i] = clob; // re-assign the parameter back                           
            }
            i++;
        }

        List<Map<String, Object>> result = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().getJdbcOperations().queryForList(sql, params);           

        if (!clobs.isEmpty())
            for (Clob c: clobs) c.free();                           

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Unfortunately, this resulted in another Oracle error:

> ORA-22922: Nonexistent LOB value

After another research I've realized that the pointer to the temporary Clob that I've assigned to the "params" parameter is empty, and most likely due to the "queryForList" **being executed in different connection** (!) than the one used for generating the temporaryClob. So I've ended up with the following:

```
JdbcTemplate t = new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(conn, false));
result = t.queryForList(sql, params);
```

which worked, but I'm afraid this is not optimal and will only be causing issues at some point in the future.

My question is, **is there any way to reuse the connection used to generate the CLOB for the actual query?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The straightforward thing to do would be to evade the overcomplicated middleware.

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> valueList(String dataSource, Object[] params, String sql) throws DataAccessException {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Clob clob = null;

    try {
      con = dataSource.getConnection();
      ps = con.prepareStatement( "SELECT samplefield FROM sampletable WHERE SDE.ST_INTERSECTS(SHAPE, SDE.ST_GEOMETRY(?, ?)) = 1 AND SHAPE IS NOT NULL" ); // probably externalize this SQL string somewhere

      // Note that Oracle's two-arg ST_GEOMETRY function takes a CLOB and an INTEGER
      // see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006z00000050000000
      Clob clob = OracleUtils.createTemporaryCLOB(conn, true, 10);                    
      clob.setString(1, (String) params[0]);
      ps.setClob( 1, clob );

      ps.setObject( 2, params[1], java.sql.Types.INTEGER );

      rs = ps.executeQuery();

      // inefficient and overdone output format, but hey.
      List<Map<String,Object>> out = new LinkedList()
      while (rs.next()) {
         Map<String,Object> oneBindingMap = new HashMap(1);
         oneBindingMap.put("samplefield", rs.getObject(1)); //again, maybe externalize the field name
         out.add( oneBindingMap );
      }
      return out;
    }
    catch ( SQLException e ) {
     throw new DataAccessException( e.getMessage(), e ); // adapt to expected Exception type
    }
    finally {
      try { if ( clob != null ) clob.free(); } catch ( Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }

      // in java 7+ you could avoid the rest of this via the try-with-resources construct
      try { if ( rs != null ) rs.close(); } catch ( Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      try { if ( ps != null ) ps.close(); } catch ( Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      try { if ( con != null ) con.close(); } catch ( Exception e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

I'm just typing this into a web page; I've not tested whether it compiles, and I'm making some assumptions about the semantics you want (e.g. the format and key name in the output maps). But I think that this should bring you pretty close to where you want to be, without having to convolute your logic to adapt it to middleware not intended to do what you want.

Alternatively, I don't see much wrong or likely to fail with your SingleConnectionDataSource hack. It just strikes me as opaque. My solution is much more verbose, but I think logically very straightforward and accessible for maintenance purposes to anyone who understands JDBC.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had this solution before (with preparedStatement), but didn't really want to mess with the result set, wanted to keep it tidy (despite the mess I've ended up with) Thanks for the bindingmap though:). Still, is there any way to tell jdbctemplate at the query operation to use the connection I already have? Or any setting anywhere that would do this whole lot for me? .. just like there used to be SetBigStringTryClob or something similar....